# In phpdoc, define class properties in separate file

Tags: php, phpdoc

I am using a framework that allows adding new components to the framework's base class. Is there any way to document these new methods without changing the frameworks files so I can click through to the method in my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend against trying to inject a subclass. If the framework instantiates the class you're extending directly, you'll need to find a way to get it to use your subclass instead.

NetBeans and PhpStorm (and probably many others) will combine elements from multiple definitions of the same class/interface. This allows you to add properties and methods to any existing class without modifying the original source.

```
/**
 * Framework controller base class.
 * Provides helpers via __call().
 */
class Framework_Controller { ... }
```

Now create a file in your code base *that you never require* containing the same class definition. Your IDE should still parse it and merge its elements with the class above:

```
if (false) { // Safety first!
    /**
     * ACME Co. controller base class.
     *
     * @method ACME_Model_User getUser Load user via authentication helper
     */
    class Framework_Controller { /* nothing to add */ }
}
```

You can try using an interface and declaring the methods normally instead of with `@method`. That is what we did with `Zend_View` since it's already an interface. I haven't tried mixing class with interface to see if PhpStorm likes it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends mainly on IDE you are using. I think you should extend base class and add there some new methods/properties with phpdoc comments. Of course changing framework's files is no solution as you already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the original class, redefine the function, with new doc, and call the parent function.
e.g.

```
class newClass extends originalClass
{
    /**
    * New PHPDoc
    */
    function functionName($a)
    {
        return parent::functionName($a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [@see](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html) or [inline @link](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/link.html) directives.